# Searching for registered device... (Cloud Endpoints Starter Template)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, database-connection, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm a .NET developer and new to Android.  I have successfully written an Android application that utilize SQLite for data storage.  Now I would like to connect the application to a Google Cloud backend.  I have followed this [instruction](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae) to Create an App Engine Connected Android Project. I'm using the Samsung Note2 to test.  On the device, it successfully Registered GCM and Endpoints Server, but when I go to the web site http//localhost:8888/ to test, it unable to find my device. It display "Searching for Registered Device..." See picture.

Can you help point me to what I could be doing wrong and how can I correct it, so Cloud Endpoints will see my device?  Thank you for your help.

Regards,

Tim

[image]

Comment: refer my answer in below thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153870/app-engine-connected-android-tutorial-localhost8888-index-not-showing-registe/16830139#16830139

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. here is what I understood before trying to resolve the issue. - go to yourproject-AppEngine-->war-->index.html

This html file is what is loaded when you go to localhost:8888. Now look inside the code of this html file. There are few javascript methods being called here. Look out for two methods

```
 // This method loads the deviceinfoendpoint and messageEndpoint libraries
 function loadGapi() {
 gapi.client.load('deviceinfoendpoint', 'v1', function() {
   updateRegisteredDeviceTable();
 });

 gapi.client.load('messageEndpoint', 'v1', function() {});
 }
```

and

```
function generateRegDeviceTable(deviceInfoItems)
```

These the two methods which do the job of getting the registered devices from datastore and display on html page. You can play around with this html file to debug the reason. In my case the reason was the backend libraries were not registered. When I am creating my own entities and using them to be displayed in the index.html then it works fine. the GCMEndpoint libraries come default when you install GPE and enabled the backend engine. Hence just redo the process and manually register the libraries and your error should be gone.