# Error in backend UI for GCM devappserver

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I get the following error when I try to access my registered devices local dev app server while testing the GCM. Can someone please help. I am following the steps as here https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae
I am able to see the registered device in //:localhost:8888/_ah/admin. But when I open //:localhost:8888/ I see the error below. The page loads but the registered devices does not show up and I see this error message below the Send button.

```
There was a problem contacting the server when attempting to list the registered devices. 
Please refresh the page and try again in a short while. Here's the error information:
<html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>    
 <title>Error 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR</title> </head> <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2> <p>Problem 
 accessing /_ah/api/rpc. Reason: <pre> INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR</pre></p><h3>Caused 
 by:</h3><pre>java.lang.NullPointerException at 
 com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.addDefaultParams(ApiServlet.java:264) at 
 com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.addParametersToMap(ApiServlet.java:257) at 
 com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.ApiServlet.doSingleBackendCall(ApiServlet.java:239) 
 at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RpcApiServlet.doSingleBackendCall
 (RpcApiServlet.java:131) at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RpcApiServlet.service
 (RpcApiServlet.java:112) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166) at 
 com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at 
 com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter
 (ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at 
 com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter
 (HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at 
 com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at  
 com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter
  (TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at 
 com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at 
 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest
 (DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369) at 
 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest
 (DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352) at 
 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter
 (DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418) at 
 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle
 (DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle
 (HandlerWrapper.java:152) at 
 com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle
 (JettyContainerService.java:438) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle
 (HandlerWrapper.java:152) at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218) at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) at 
 org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409) at 
 org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582) </pre> 
 <hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> 
 <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Please refer my answer below.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153870/app-engine-connected-android-tutorial-localhost8888-index-not-showing-registe/16830139#16830139